# Cosets in modular arithmetic not following rules of group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Note: I am very new to abstract algebra. Thus pardon me if the question is naive.

Say I have a group G = {0, 1, 2, 3} under addition (modular/clock arithmetic) and subgroup H = {0, 1}

if I start finding left cosets of H,

- (0) + {0, 1} = {0, 1}
- (1) + {0, 1} = {1, 2}
- (2) + {0, 1} = {2, 3}
- (3) + {0, 1} = {3, 0}

However cosets should either be disjoint or similar but if you pick any two cosets here, they overlap. What is the issue here?

Comment: Your $H$ is *not* a subgroup. $\{0,2\}$ is,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $\{0,1\}$ is not a subgroup. (It's not closed.) Try with $\{0,2\}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correct point out. Feel silly to miss this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. That's why we're here.